# How to filter ssh banner when using python paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am wondering how to ask paramiko to filter the ssh banner.

[Source Code from others](http://media.commandline.org.uk/code/ssh.txt)

When I execute a command, contents of the banner come with result together.

Something like below

```
pprint(connection.execute('date'))

#['Welcome to my shell\n', 'Fri Jul 11 15:07:11 HKT 2014\n']
```

Method I have tried

```
self._transport.get_banner() # always return none
```

I have checked out a bit of the paramiko source code. There are codes for parsing banner internally. But the question is how can I make sure of them to do my job well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround for filtering banner contents

```
# Assume you are using the source code I posted
conn = Connection(HOST, USERNAME, PW)
banner = conn.execute('\n') # Fetch banner content
dateResult = conn.execute('date') # Target command result

# since banner is always a subset of dataResult, you can do the following
ret = dataResult.replace(banner, '')
print ret # ret is the answer you want
```

Although this workaround solve my problem, I will be happy to know if there is a native alternative on paramiko.