# how to supress the below banner,Authentication (publickey) successful! and Connected version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.6.1 Messages on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
def node():
    ssh=paramiko.SSHClient() 
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(SelfIP,SSHport)
    stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('ls -lrt')
    outlines=stdout.readlines()
    resp=''.join(outlines)
    cmd = "exit"
    print("RESP",resp)
    logging.info(resp)
```

node()
    Hi all, above is my function to perform ssh using paramiko and and log 
    file will be generated with below info. How do we suppress or make sure 
    the below lines should not appear in log file, any suggestions?

```
2019-03-18 15:30:41,226 INFO Connected (version 2.0, client 
OpenSSH_6.6.1)
2019-03-18 15:30:41,444 INFO Auth banner:
Attention! Unauthorized remote access is strictly prohibited!

2019-03-18 15:30:41,445 INFO Authentication (publickey) successful!
Thanks Kavi
```

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692174/how-to-filter-ssh-banner-when-using-python-paramiko

Comment: Hi Devesh, i tried your approach but it does not work  as my requirement is to not make the banner appear in log file but i still get the output ....2019-05-01 22:46:01,983 INFO Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.4)
2019-05-01 22:46:02,244 INFO Auth banner:
Attention! Unauthorized remote access is strictly prohibited!


2019-05-01 22:46:02,244 INFO Authentication (publickey) successful!

Comment: Okay let me try more and see what I can come up with

Comment: sure .. objective is to not get into log file such banners messages.